# Run command only once after Django app startup

Tags: python, django

I have a django-based function that needs to be run only once in Django, when the app boots up. The tricky part is that:

- The code in question heavily uses django ORM, so apps have to be ready at that point,
- The code should run only once - e.g. not once per every worker, but exactly once per "website" (regardless of whether it's deployed via gunicorn with a dozen of workers, or run locally via the built-in development web-server),
- The code should only run once the app boots, but NOT by running other management commands. The code can take a while to complete, and I don't want it to trigger each time I run `makemigrations` or `shell`.

I could, theoretically, just introduce a locking mechanism and let it run somewhere in `AppConfig.ready()` method, but that would still run in all management commands as well.

Since the app is packaged in Docker, I've been also thinking about simply wrapping the code in a separate management command and running it in the entry point, just before the app is being started. That seems to do the trick, but it will be done *automatically* only in that particular container - if somebody runs a local development server to work on the app on his own, he might not be aware that an additional command should be run.

I've searched through the documentation and it doesn't look like Django has a way to do this natively on its own. Perhaps there's a better approach that I can't think of?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same need. I run the startup code in `AppConfig.ready()`, depending on an environment variable that you have to set when you don't want the startup code to be executed.

```
SKIP_STARTUP = settings.DEBUG or os.environ.get('SKIP_STARTUP')
class myapp(AppConfig):
    def ready(self):
        if not SKIP_STARTUP:
            <startup stuff>
```

Comment: That sorts out the problem of running only in management commands (e.g. setting the variable everywhere, aside from app deployment). But it doesn't address the issue of allowing only one instance of the code to be run.

Comment: The method `AppConfig.ready()` runs once at django startup (I am using 1.11). No sort of lock is needed.

Comment: Does this also apply to gunicorn, where there are multiple workers?

Comment: I don't know: I am using a regular apache server.

Comment: @albar I'm using AppConfig.ready() and it's being called on management commands in Django 1.11